# Is a sealed attic appropriate for Southern California?

Tags: insulation, attic

I have a two-story house. Half the house has a cathedral ceiling (which will be left as is) and the other half has a traditional attic with no soffits. The only ventilation in the attic comes from two gable vents at each end of the house.

How should I insulate this type of attic?  I am contemplating adding insulation to the bottom of the roof deck and adding more insulation to flooring in attic; I think this is called a sealed attic.  Is this appropriate for my climate?

Answer (score 1):

If I were building the house in southern California then I wouldn't do this, especially if you were using asphalt shingles.

An unventilated attic in a warm climate like this can get extremely hot and will greatly decrease the life expectancy of asphalt shingles.  Over time they will start to curl prematurely from the heat.  If I were to do this I would insist the following courses of action:

- Heavily insulate without sealing gables
- Have at least a 1 foot overhang with ventilated soffits
- If 1 foot overhang is not possible, then install an attic fan to assist in proper ventilation of the attic
- If neither of these are possible then forgo asphalt shingles for something more appropriate for extreme heat like terracotta or slate shingles.

Comment: Not having adequate ventilation tends to void shingle warranties. That was the first thing mentioned when I did my re-roof.